# swf links with php becomes not functioning

Tags: flash, swfobject

I had a SWF file and I try to embed it into my HTML page using :

```
<div>   
        <object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="140">
            <param name="movie" value="Scratch.swf" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Scratch.swf" width="1920" height="1080">
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <div>
                <h1>Alternative content</h1>
                <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
            </div>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

While my SWF suppose to be like this :

[image]

I get this instead while I try to link with xampp :

[image]

It suppose to be a fully functional SWF file with blocks but what I get is just the player.

Comment: like this ? means what , no reference

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Kho-Chung-ning What's the name of your "full" SWF, "test.swf" or "Scratch.swf" ? Verify the name (**only one name should be used**) that you should include in your HTML code.

Comment: @akmozo I had change the name of it but it still remain the same, I want to editor block to be functional rather than just display it. I saw someone manage to do it but I don't know how.
http://www.programmingbasics.org/en/downloads/scratchgames/scratch/

Comment: @NirpendraPatel, I had hyperlink my words with the image not sure why it dint went out thou.

Comment: The code can run as I want when its not connected to localhost/xampp but once I link it, it just show the player

Comment: @KhoChungNing This is the URL of that SWF : http://www.programmingbasics.org/en/downloads/scratchgames/scratch/ScratchFlashDevelop.swf.

Comment: @akmozo,yea but I cant access the code and I dont know what i did wrong

Comment: @KhoChungNing I mean that you should use that SWF in your HTML code. Download it to your local machine then use it.

Comment: @akmozo the swf file is already inside my local machine but i create a web that has an editor that will open the swf file. When I did not open mySQL , the swf file works perfectly fine but once I open with mySQL it changed to the player instead of the editor.